# Searching number with a list of numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a requirement where i have list of Numeric ID's. The ID's are in the following format:

`3131010301` : the first 6 are assigned to Managers and rest of the 4 numbers are assigned to to his team mates. Each team member would have a ID with a prefix of the Managers ID's and only last 4 digits changing per team member.

My need is to identify the ID's based on Managers ID and collate all information together for his team. This would be a huge data set to search.

Do we have anything in the line of INSTR which can be used for Numeric's?

Appreciate your inputs and ofcourse please let me know if am not clear.

Comment: VBA's`INSTR` does work with numbers. In Excel proper, `MID`, `SEARCH`, etc. work with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your spreadsheet looks like this

[image]

I wrote a code that will separate the managers and members IDs to 2 different columns

[image]

Column B has the first 6 digits - which I think you called the Managers IDs

Column C has the 4 digit team member ID

So, set up your spreadsheet to look like the first picture and then run the code

```
Option Explicit

Sub ManagersAndTheirTeams()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ReDim arr(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1) As String

    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Long
    For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range("A" & i)
        arr(i - 1) = r
        Set r = Nothing
    Next i

    RemoveDuplicate arr

    Columns("B:C").NumberFormat = "@"

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        For j = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set r = Range("A" & j)
            If StrComp(Left(arr(i), 6), Left(r, 6), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Range("B" & j) = Left(arr(i), 6)
                Range("C" & j) = Right(r, 4)
            End If
            Set r = Nothing
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        For j = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set r = Range("B" & j)
            If StrComp(Left(arr(i), 6), r, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                c = c + 1
                If c > 1 Then
                    r.ClearContents
                End If
            End If
            Set r = Nothing
        Next j
        c = 0
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub RemoveDuplicate(ByRef StringArray() As String)
    Dim lowBound$, UpBound&, A&, B&, cur&, tempArray() As String
    If (Not StringArray) = True Then Exit Sub
    lowBound = LBound(StringArray): UpBound = UBound(StringArray)
    ReDim tempArray(lowBound To UpBound)
    cur = lowBound: tempArray(cur) = StringArray(lowBound)
    For A = lowBound + 1 To UpBound
        For B = lowBound To cur
            If LenB(tempArray(B)) = LenB(StringArray(A)) Then
                If InStrB(1, StringArray(A), tempArray(B), vbBinaryCompare) = 1 Then Exit For
            End If
        Next B
        If B > cur Then cur = B: tempArray(cur) = StringArray(A)
    Next A
    ReDim Preserve tempArray(lowBound To cur): StringArray = tempArray
End Sub
```